# Creating subset list , in a list based on length of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have this code here: which takes user input and adds it to a list until they input to stop. At that point, it sorts the list items based on length.

What I am trying to do is put each word the user enters into a list of words with the same length. Like 2-letter words are put into one list, 3-letter words are put into another list.

When complete, I'm trying to return a list containing all of the individual word lists that were created.

So far all I have achieved is organizing them and then adding them to another list that outputs the list as many time as word entered.

```
def wordsList():
    stop = "stop"

    sentence = []
    sentence2 = []
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a word: ")
        if word == stop:
            # exit the loop
            break
        sentence.append(word)


        sentence.sort(key=len)
        cat= len(sentence)
        for sublist in sentence:

            sentence.append(sentence)
            # sublist.insert(sentence)
        # sentence2=[sentence]


    # print(" ".join(sentence)) # Goes through the list and finds a smaller word and convert the list of words into a single string, each word separated by a space.
    print(sentence)

wordsList()
```

Comment: You need to fix up your indentation here, this code can't possibly run as written, and it's unclear whether some code is part of the `while` loop or not (starting from `sentence.sort` it shouldn't be, but it's unclear if that's part of your problem). The cost dealing with sublists is completely unclear; seems like you think `sort` is grouping for you? Hint: It isn't, though `itertools.groupby` could do that (or you skip both `sort` and `groupby` and use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` to accumulate and group directly). Either way, this isn't a [MCVE]; please provide example inputs/outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

I'd recommend using a dictionary where the keys are the length of the words and the values are the list of words that have that length. Here is a potential implementation:

```
import collections
STOP = "stop"

def wordsList():
    words = collections.defaultdict(list)
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a word: ")
        if word == STOP:
            break
        length = len(word)
        words[length].append(word)
    return list(words.values())
```

Comment: where is the dictionary that gets created?

Answer (score 0):

This is what `itertools.groupby` is made for. First you'll need a function that gets the length of one word, which is built-in as `len`. Then you can sort using that keyfunction, and group using it too.

```
import itertools

some_lst = [...]  # user list of various length words
some_lst.sort(key=len)
groups = itertools.groupby(some_lst, key=len)
```

This builds `groups` into a list of tuples. Each tuple has format:

```
(len(words), words_with_that_len)
```

you're only really interested in the second element of each tuple, so pull that out.

```
result = [list(sublst) for _, sublst in groups]
```

---

You could also build this yourself with `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections

result_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for word in some_lst:
    result_dict[len(word)].append(word)
```

`result_dict` is now a dictionary of lists. To get a sorted list of lists you can run it through a list comprehension with `sorted` and `dict.items`

```
result = [v for _,v in sorted(result_dict.items())]
```

Comment: You need `list(sublst)` in that final listcomp, or `result` will be a `list` of mostly empty generators; every time `groups` advances, the previously returned generators become defunct.